# TikZ grid lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\draw[step=1.0,black,thin] (0.5,0.5) grid (5.5,4.5);
```

which I would like to have generate grid lines in the Y direction at `y = {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5}` and grid lines in the X direction at `x = {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5}`.

However, I get grid lines at `y = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}` and `x = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}` with half cells around the edges of the grid. So instead of having a closed uniform grid, I get one with open edges and two half cells at the borders.

Does anybody know why it doesn't honor the starting point and stride?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The points specify where the grid lines begin and end.  The brown grid lines below are the ones you want, but note that that the blue lines which were specified with `(0.5,0.5) grid (5.5,4.5)` do indeed begin at `x=0.5`, and `y=0.5` and end at `x=5.5` and `y=4.5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\xMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\xMax}{6}%
\newcommand*{\yMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\yMax}{6}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {\xMin,...,\xMax} {
        \draw [very thin,gray] (\i,\yMin) -- (\i,\yMax)  node [below] at (\i,\yMin) {$\i$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {\yMin,...,\yMax} {
        \draw [very thin,gray] (\xMin,\i) -- (\xMax,\i) node [left] at (\xMin,\i) {$\i$};
    }

\draw [step=1.0,blue, very thick] (0.5,0.5) grid (5.5,4.5);
\draw [very thick, brown, step=1.0cm,xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm] (0.5,0.5) grid +(5.5,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A newbie reflection: from this example and several others I got the idea of grid line coordinates: it uses multiples of step (which is 1cm by default), and the parameters in `(startx, starty) grid (endx, endy)` basically define the clipping region whereas in order to shift it we need to use the `xshift` `yshift` that you mentioned. It seems so counterintuitive to me that it is so much 'centered' around the origin (I do find it convenient though, it's just surprising). I was trying to find the grid shift parameters in the TikZ documentation for the `grid` command and found nothing.

Comment: @AndreySurovtsev: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). I think the authors tried to not have more options than necessary. Since `xshift` and `yshift` are used throughout to shift the coordinate system, it is convienient to use the same options for shifting grids. I agree that when starting out there is a lot to take in with `TikZ`, but once you use it for a while things get easier, at least the basics.

Answer (score 37):

You can use the `xshift` and `yshift` options:

```
\draw[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (0.5,0.5) grid (5.5,4.5);
```

Comment: Is it possible to "easily" add the labels?

Comment: Probably not, but perhaps you can put it in a separate command, so that you can use e.g. `\gridlabel{xmin}{ymin}{xmax}{ymax}`?