# Grid in LaTeX help

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi am new to latex and trying to recreate the grid as shown in the image, any help at all would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: There's a cheaty way by exploiting a special dash pattern: `\draw[line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm, line width=3pt] (0,0) grid[xstep=1cm,ystep=0](10,10);` Otherwise you can use loops directly: `\fill[radius=1.5pt] foreach \x in {0,...,10} {foreach \y in {0,...,10} {(\x,\y) circle[]}};`

Comment: Welcome. // Here are two examples, which use \foreach https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45808/tikz-grid-lines, https://texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-graph-model/ . // You may also want to have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach+tikz-pgf and perhaps modify the search. // Here are some tikz sources https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674254/245790 .

Comment: Check the manual of `tikz` or take a look at the VisualTikZ examples found here: https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a "do it for me" site. ---GOM